# Is there a passive infinitive?

Tags: passive-voice, infinitive

If I say something can *be* changed, for example, how would I say that in Latin? Would I say *id X potest*, or is there some other construction for this? The context doesn't really matter, but it's for my *Commentarium Latinum* entry about drawing people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a passive infinitive.
If something can be loved, seen, pulled, or heard, you can say *amari/videri/trahi/audiri potest*.
In the first, second, and third conjugation you just replace the final *-e* of the active infinitive with *-ī*.
In the third conjugation you replace *-ere* with *-ī*.

I interpreted your question to mean that you wanted a present passive infinitive.
The active and passive infinitives also have past and future forms.
Some of these forms require an auxiliary verb (*esse* or *iri*).
If you want to know more about different infinitives, please consult a Latin grammar and ask a new question if something is unclear.

Comment: On your last sentence: sort of. There's a perfect active, and *esse* has the lonesome honor of a future active (*fore*), but all the other infinitives are periphrastic.

Comment: @Anonym True, many of the infinitives are periphrastic (*visurum esse, videre, vidisse, visum iri, videri, visum esse* and similarly for other verbs), but they are there nevertheless. They are indeed morphologically different, but it has little effect on their use (gender and number for the ones with *esse*).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I think one could take exception to the use of the word *forms*.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I expanded a little. I wanted to keep the mention of other infinitives shallow; the details are beside the point here but I thought the OP should be aware of their existence.